# How can I get the ca-certificates.crt?

Tags: docker, certificates

My docker get error "x509 certificate signed by unknown authority" and then i find that my ubuntu contianer missing file `ca-certificates.crt` on `/etc/ssl/certs/` or `/usr/local/share/certificates/`. The solution of this error is add **ca-certificates.crt** to the */usr/local/share/certificates/** folder and run `update-ca-certificates` command. But my problem is I dont know where to get that .crt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I fix that:

```sh
docker run -v /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt --name test image
```

I create a bind volume from file ca-certificates.crt on the docker host(Centos) to the container and let container use it for verify trusted ca.

Comment: In fact you just need to create and copy `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in the docker container. No need to mount the entire directory

Comment: Not sure why that didn't work for me, but I had to create a Dockerfile:
`FROM ubuntu:22.04`, `RUN apt update`, `RUN apt install -y ca-certificates`, `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/cat", "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"]`

and then run:
`docker build -t ubuntu-tmp && docker run --rm ubuntu-tmp > ca-certificates.crt`

Answer (score 0):

To [get certificates](https://www.johnmackenzie.co.uk/post/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-docker-and-nginx/), run similar to the next command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout nginx/my-site.com.key -x509 -days 365 -out nginx/my-site.com.crt
```

Also, you could use [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/bradrydzewski/a6090115b3fecfc25280):

> ```
> DAYS=1460
> PASS=$(openssl rand -hex 16)
>
> # remove certificates from previous execution.
> rm -f *.pem *.srl *.csr *.cnf
>
>
> # generate CA private and public keys
> echo 01 > ca.srl
> openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca-key.pem -passout pass:$PASS 2048
> openssl req -subj '/CN=*/' -new -x509 -days $DAYS -passin pass:$PASS -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem
> ```